# Data studio regex calculated field replace after |

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm having trouble with the formula to replace page title after `|`, using `\|` it just says "`Could not parse formula`". Can anyone help?

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page Title, '\|(.*)', '')
```

So `Page name | Company name` should turn to `Page name`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx, it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page Title, ' *\\|.*', '')
```

or

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page Title, ' *[|].*', '')
```

You need to double the escaping backslashes or put `|` into a character class, and add a quantified space before to "trim" the value. You don't need the group, so I suggest removing it.